# How to get the Field type when reading the Schema Field?

Tags: core-service, schema

I am reading all the  Schemas using core service from the Building Block folder,  after reading the schema, I am reading all the field from a particular Schema. I successfully get all the field from a particularly Schema,  but i didn't find any method for get the field type in the "ItemFieldDefinitionData" class then how i get the field type.

i  wrote following code for reading the schema and all the field.

```
   OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData f=new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();

    ArrayOfItemType ai=new ArrayOfItemType();
        List<ItemType> cpList =ai.getItemType() ;
        cpList.add(ItemType.SCHEMA);
       f.setItemTypes(ai);
        ArrayOfIdentifiableObjectData systemWideListSchema = client.getList("tcm:397-27454-2",f);

        System.out.println("in read");

        for (IdentifiableObjectData iod : systemWideListSchema.getIdentifiableObjectData()) 
            {
            SchemaData schemaData=(SchemaData)iod;
            System.out.println(schemaData.getTitle()+""+schemaData.getId());

               SchemaData sdata=(SchemaData) client.read(schemaData.getId(),new ReadOptions());
               SchemaFieldsData schemaFieldsData = client.readSchemaFields(sdata.getId(), false, null);
              ArrayOfItemFieldDefinitionData aFiled = schemaFieldsData.getFields();  
              List<ItemFieldDefinitionData> l= aFiled.getItemFieldDefinitionData(); 

              for(ItemFieldDefinitionData i:l)
              { System.out.println("in schema Filed");
                 System.out.println(i.getName());
              //Here i want to get the type of field
              }
              }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ItemFieldDefinitionData` is the root class in the hierarchy:

```
ItemFieldDefinitionData
     ComponentLinkFieldDefinitionData
     DateFieldDefinitionData
     EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinitionData
     ExternalLinkFieldDefinitionData
     KeywordFieldDefinitionData
     MultiLineTextFieldDefinitionData
     MultimediaLinkFieldDefinitionData
     NumberFieldDefinitionData
     SingleLineTextFieldDefinitionData
     XhtmlFieldDefinitionData
```

So you can get the exact class with `GetType`, like `i.GetType().Name`, for example. This will return you the underlying class, which corresponds to the field type, for instance `DateFieldDefinitionData`

Comment: Thanks @user978511 by using the method getClass() i get instance of particually field Type class

Comment: You can also do a strongly-typed check by using something like "if (i is MultiLineTextFieldDefinitionData) { ... }"

Comment: Yes, but he wanted to print out the field type

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of work, you should definitely look at the [Change Content or Metadata](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/ChangeContentOrMetadata) recipe in the Tridion Cookbook. There you will find a very useful library that exposes, among other things, the field types.

Comment: Update: user978511 and I seem to have posted simultaneously... so for clarity - the library I mentioned exposes the type as a property, and you still have to read the name yourself, so it's really the same technique. Even so, I'd still check out the library.